# Sharing a partition between Arch & Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, arch-linux, fstab

I've just installed Arch linux to go alongside Ubuntu, and I'm having some trouble sharing a partition between the two. I've created it in both distros' fstabs, looking like this:

```
UUID=<uuid>    /data    ext4    defaults    0    1
```

... with `<uuid>` being the partition's actual UUID. It mounts fine in both distros and I can access it, but in Ubuntu it has the actual files in that it is meant to have - they were copied there from the Ubuntu distro in the first place - whereas in Arch it just has a lost+found folder.

Could anyone please give me a pointer as to where I might be going wrong with this? Do I need to set UID/GIDs?

Thanks in advance, and also afterwards

Comment: Do you use dual boot or you access filesystem at the same time via virtual machine?

Comment: @p0rc0_r0ss0 - yes - I should have said - it's a dual boot.

Comment: so, if you `sudo fstab -l` in both systems your `/data` is (for example) `/dev/sda5`
And in both fstabs you have `blkid /dev/sda5` UID?
Try `df -h` on both systems and see if drive size matches.

Comment: Check with `findmnt /data` on both sides to make sure neither of them have another filesystem mount on /data (over or not the desired one).

Comment: Also check with `lsblk -f` / `blkid` to make sure there isn't a "clone", in case you did something silly.

Comment: Thanks for the responses here - I've gone through the steps you suggest and I still can't see what's wrong with it, so I'm just going to move the contents elsewhere and re-create the partition. Thanks for the help though.